# How to get child views from Backbone Marionette's composite view?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, marionette, composite

I am working on an application based on Backbone and Marionette. I am using composite view to show an table now I want to update multiple child view's together So I want their object and model. So to access them

I read [this method](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.babysitter#retrieving-views). I tried them on composite view object but none of the method is working and throwing the error message

> CheckInOutCollectionView.findByIndex is not a function

How can I access the child view object?

Answer (score 13):

If you know the index of the child view:

```
var child = collectionView.children.findByIndex(0)
```

If you want to find the child view for a particular model:

```
var child = collectionView.children.findByModel(model)
```

This works because `CollectionView.prototype.children` is a Babysitter `ChildViewContainer` instance.

This works for `CompositeView` instances as well because `CompositeView` extends `CollectionView`.

Comment: I am using version 1.1.0, this functions are available from 2.0 onwards.

Comment: Sir do you know how to use findbycustomIndexer().